# How to ignore failure when file does exist when downloading with WinSCP script

Tags: scripting, batch-processing, sftp, winscp

Running a script to get a file from SFTP server, however this is recurring job and should still succeed if no file exist, is there an option I can specify?

```
option batch on
option confirm off
option transfer binary
open sftp://server -timeout=60
password
get /File/2_04-28-2015.txt  D:\Files
close
exit
```

Getting this result:

```
Can't get attributes of file 'File/2_04-28-2015.txt'.
    No such file or directory.
    Error code: 2
```

Tried setting `failonnomatch`:

```
winscp> option failonnomatch on
Unknown option 'failonnomatch'.
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell WinSCP to ignore absent file, when using a specific file name.

But you can [check the file existence prior to the actual download](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#scripting).

---

Easy alternative hack is to use a [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) (note the trailing `*`) and set the [`failonnomatch off`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option):

```
option failonnomatch off
get /File/2_04-28-2015.txt*  D:\Files\
```

(if you are getting *"Unknown option 'failonnomatch'"*, then you have an old version of WinSCP).

Comment: File mask option was very helpful to avoid clutter outside of the script. This is my first time using WinSCP and of course the scripting. Unfortunately I did have to fail on a "get" and do some googling to find this hack, which I couldn't find on your site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MGET instead of GET?  It shouldn't fail, just not transfer anything if there's nothing there.

Comment: mget 'File/2_04-28-2015.txt'  D:\Files
Can't get attributes of file 'File/2_04-28-2015.txt'.
No such file or directory.
Error code: 2
Error message from server (en): File not foun

Comment: The `mget` is an alias to `get` in WinSCP. So it behaves identically.